# DBCursor isnt' recongnized by IDE

Tags: java, mongodb

I'm using IntelliJ for creating a java application that uses the mongodb java driver. I'm having a problem where my IDE doesn't recognize DBCursor as a type. I'm using version 3.12.7 of the driver.

Comment: How are you adding the dependency to your project? Sounds like your gradle/maven needs to synchronize dependencies.

Comment: `<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
    <artifactId>mongodb-driver-sync</artifactId>
    <version>3.12.7</version>
    </dependency>`

Is this what you mean?